# Restrict the global variable should not take assign value which is done outside the class initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one global variable isSave in my controller.

```
private bool isSave;
```

There is Get Method in samecontroller. I want that viewbag given below should be true/false based on condition

```
ViewBag.EmailConfirmationSent = false;

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!isSave)
        ViewBag.EmailConfirmationSent = false;
}
```

There is post method in same controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProfileViewModel profileViewModel)
{
    bool isSave = SaveDone(); //let say it return true
    ViewBag.EmailConfirmationSent = true;
    return View("Profile", profileViewModel); // redirect to Index method
}
```

Now when I make the viewBag true(in post method), it should not change in index method. To restrict that I have used one global variable isSave but whenever it hits the index the global variable "isSave" is always coming false and again my viewBag become false which I don't want.
Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use like that, if you want to preserve data between two requests use TempData instead

Comment: I could not able to apply the logic. Could u plz help me. My intention is, in  Index method(first time hit) I have set the ViewBag as false but in post method I want to make it true and return type of post method is Index. So in 2nd time I don't want that my viewBag should became false.

Comment: Please go through the following links, http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1074, http://petermcintyre.com/2013/01/27/asp-net-mvc-data-persistence-choices/